# Content of Grid list to fill the height

Tags: angular-material

I am placing content in the grid list component and I want the grid tile to grow accordingly to the content it has. I tried to use rowHeight="fit" as documentation states but it doesn't seems to work.

[Here an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2alu7b)

Answer (score 0):

MatGridList overall size is directly related to the `rowHeight` setting. The default `rowHeight` value is a ratio `1:1` (which means column width equals row height).

When you use a ratio, the list will have a fixed width/height ratio overall, so if the list can't grow in one direction because of window or layout restrictions, it can't grow in any direction. This is why your example looks the way it does. If you expand the width of the window, you'll see the list expand vertically as well. You can set a different rowHeight value to make the tiles taller than wide such as `rowHeight="1:2"` (that seems backwards to me but that's how it works).

When you use `rowHeight="fit"`, this doesn't fit the list to the content, it fits the row heights to the list height, but as noted in the documentation, you must set a height on the list or a parent for this to work properly.

Setting a fixed value for `rowHeight` does what it sounds like.